# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, docker-machine

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory